# the content of the page doesn't show on wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, themes

I am using WordPress to create website I have added a php page to the them and trying to use it but the problem is that when I open the page as stand-alone page it works fine but when I tried with the **wordpress** it doesn't show anything. What is the problem and how to fix it ?

My question is how to create a new page to the website with keeping all the CSS and style.

I will appreciate any help.

referring to this url [How to Create a Custom Page in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/)

1. copy  file page.php
2. add this line
3. add in the custom php page
4. in wordpress select in the template the **create template**

This is how the webpage looks if the code is written oustside the WordPress editor: 
[image]

[image]

This is how the webpage looks if the code is written inside the WordPress editor

[image]
[image]

This is how the webpage looks if the code is written stand alone

[image]

## code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Form Validation</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified BootStarp CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#textarea").hide()
      $("#droplistID").change(function() {
        $(this).val() == 'select' ? $("#textarea").hide() : $("#textarea").show();
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>
        Send Post Data to AJAX
      </h1>
      <form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" id="myform" action="#" onsubmit="return submitForm();" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-datam">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading">Form</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name" class="col-md-4">Date *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Title" class="col-md-4">Title *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="phone" placeholder="Enter the Title" required/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  ">
                  <label for="category" class="col-md-4">select Category *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select name="droplist" id="droplistID">
                           <option id = "option1" value="select" selected>Select</option>
                           <option id = "option2" value="category 1">category 34</option>
                           <option id = "option3" value="category 2">category 2</option>
                           <option id = "option4" value="category 3">category 3</option>
                       </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div id="textarea">
                  <div class="form-group  ">
                    <label for="text" class="col-md-4">Enter a text </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <textarea cols="60" rows="30"> </textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group  ">
                  <label for="image" class="col-md-4">Select Image </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
          <center>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
          </center>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by saying "Stand Alone Page" . How did you do that ?

Comment: @Jackson i meant its php page not inside the wordpress  theme

Comment: Have you created "page-your_page_name.php" file in yur FTP project location and have you created a page in wordpress backend using the same slug "your_page_name" adding no content in the text editor. Have You ?

Comment: @Jackson  i am using local server XAMPP ====
i have created a php file called ajwa2.php====
and i have created a page in wordpress  i called ajwa2==
this is the link **Permalink: http://127.0.0.1:8012/wordpress/ajwa2/ **

Comment: can you please add the screenshot of both stand alone mode and when you try to open the page using wordpress

Comment: ok i will edit my question and add  screenshots

Comment: Okay so you want the style of stand alone page ... right ?

Comment: i want to make the content showed on the web page even if i do not write the cod in the wordpress editor

Comment: for that create a page named "page-your_name" inside the themes folder. and write the code inside that. Come to wordpress backend and add the page with the same slug and click publish